# How to pass a jdbcTemplate.queryForList statement as an List<Map<String, Object>> to another method

Tags: java, mysql, spring, list, dictionary

I'm trying to send a  jdbcTemplate.queryForList statement in the method viewEmployees from my class EmployeeDAO to another method called EmployeeServiceImpl.

I'm using Spring Boot..

```
    public class EmployeeDAO{                                         

        public List<Map<String,Object>> viewEmployees() {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        //This is where i make the sql-statement
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM employee");

        //here I want to return an List<Map<String,Object>> of rows
        return rows;
    }
}
```

This is the other method where I want the return value sent to:

```
  public List viewEmployees(){List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = employeeDAO.viewEmployees();
        //For loop of rows (Employees)
        for (Map row : rows) {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId((int) (row.get("id")));
            employee.setName((String) (row.get("name")));
            employee.setPosition((String) (row.get("position")));
            employee.setProvision_goal((int) (row.get("provision_goal")));
            employee.setProvision_accumulated((int) (row.get("provision_accumulated")));
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAO.viewEmployees(EmployeeDAO.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.services.EmployeeServiceImpl.viewEmployees(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
```

How do I return the rows?

My datasource is defined:

```
@Qualifier("dataSource")
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
```

When I combine both methods, I have no problem with the code. The problem seems to be when I try to return rows in EmployeeDAO.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I define dataSource

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db1");
JdbcTemplate temp = new JdbcTemplate();
temp.setDataSource(ds);
```

**Context.xml**

```
  <Resource auth="Container" 
   driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
   maxActive="100" 
   maxIdle="30" 
   maxWait="10000" 
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
   name="jdbc/revplatformdb" 
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="20000"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   password="xxx"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1"
   username="database1"/>
```